# Postgres treats character varying as integer

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin

I have a column in a relation schema of data type `character varying`. Though the column is of `character varying` I have been inserting data of `integer` type and did not realize the error until I actually needed to input data of character varying type. This is the error I get

```
insert into my_table(bad_column) values ('bad column');  

Error: invalid input syntax for integer: "bad column".
```

What might be the problem? I have confirmed the data type of the column by running the code below and it actually returns character varying

```
select pg_typeof(bad_column) FROM my_table limit 10
```

Comment: [Please write a MCVE.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: you need to provide sufficient into for us to try to replicate the issue, not enough info has been provided. DDL to setup that column & sample inserts of integers

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statement for that table (do not post code in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The real table is actuable very big about 20 columns posting the whole table here would create more confusion

Comment: @clemensThe real table is actuable very big about 20 columns posting the whole table here would create more confusion

Comment: @Used_By_AlreadyThe real table is actuable very big about 20 columns posting the whole table here would create more confusion

Comment: No, it would not "create confusion" - it would enable people to find a solution to the problem you have. Given the error message I am pretty sure that Postgres is correct and that you have defined the column as `integer` - but as you don't want to show us the table there is nothing we can do.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please check the edit i have confirmed the data type and it shows character varying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether the table definition has a check constraint, e.g.

```
create table test(bad_column varchar check (bad_column::int > 0));
insert into test (bad_column) values ('a text');

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "a text"
```

The other option is that there is a cast to integer of the column in a trigger.

Both cases are rather bizzare solutions, you should alter the type of the column to integer.

Comment: I checked the table description and it showed an index that I had created without specifying the data type but postgres automatically casted it to integer.